# Update base layer on toggle button change in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers, jquery

I have an html toggle button and try to toggle update between two layers (baselayer and earthlayer) when it's changed.

I am assigning a variable and change the value to the corresponding layer. Perhaps something is wrong and the layer is not getting updated.

```
var MapView = baseLayer;
$("#mapview").change(function () {//when toggle button is changed
  if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    MapView = earthlayer;
  else
    MapView = baseLayer;  
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [MapView],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([33.33386, 35.14710]),
    zoom: 14
  })
});
```

Answer (score 2):

With `var map = new ol.Map` you create new map with each toggle. Map creation has to be moved out of toggle processing. There you just add/remove required layer, something like this:

```
var mapLayer = baseLayer;
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [mapLayer],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([33.33386, 35.14710]),
    zoom: 14
  })
});

$("#mapview").change(function () {//when toggle button is changed
  var newMapLayer;

  if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    newMapLayer = earthlayer;
  else
    newMapLayer = baseLayer;  

  if (newMapLayer != mapLayer) {
    map.addLayer(newMapLayer);
    map.removeLayer(mapLayer);
    mapLayer = newMapLayer;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what i did and worked. Note that i add each layer at position 0. So it does not replace any other layer. It adds them as baselayers.

```
 $("#mapview").change(function () {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')){
    map.removeLayer(roadlayer);
    map.getLayers().insertAt(0, earthlayer);
  }
  else{
    map.removeLayer(earthlayer);
    map.getLayers().insertAt(0, roadlayer);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do what most layer switchers do and set the visibility (a little refinement is needed to set the initial visibility)

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [baseLayer, earthlayer],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([33.33386, 35.14710]),
    zoom: 14
  })
});

$("#mapview").change(function () {//when toggle button is changed
  var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
  baseLayer.setVisible(!checked);
  earthLayer.setVisible(checked);
});
```